# How to set swiperevealLayout on any recyclerview items click to close the open layout?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm new to android development . I'm using this library https://github.com/chthai64/SwipeRevealLayout to implement swipelayout on my recyclerview.

However , it can only swipe to open and close but i want to implement when one item is swiped open then on click of any items will close the current opened one.
I just could't figure out how it works.

I'm sorry if my topic question doesn't match what i'm describing, I'm not a native english speaker.

I'm able to set ViewBinderHelper.setOpenOnly(true) . It can only swipe one item at a time.
I tried to test if swipelayout is open or close by holder.swipelayout.isOpen , but it doesn't do anything.

Any Ideas or Help would be extremely appreciated , thank you.

This is my Adapter Class

```
class ReturnAdapter(val context : Context , val deliveryinfo : MutableList<BookingInfo>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ReturnAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

private val viewbinderhelper = ViewBinderHelper()
init {
    viewbinderhelper.setOpenOnlyOne(true)
 }

 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
     val view=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.return_model_layout, parent, false)
    return MyViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return deliveryinfo.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val deliveryinformation = deliveryinfo[position]
    holder.setData(deliveryinformation)
    viewbinderhelper.bind(holder.swipelayout, deliveryinformation.booking_id.toString())

  }  

    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

   val swipelayout : SwipeRevealLayout = 
   itemView.findViewById(R.id.swipelayout)
}
```

My XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <com.chauthai.swipereveallayout.SwipeRevealLayoutandroid:layout_height="match_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  app:mode="same_level"
  app:dragEdge="right"
  android:id="@+id/swipelayout">

        <!-- Your secondary layout here -->
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="70dp"
              android:id="@+id/deletereturn"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:clickable="true"
              android:foreground="? 
              android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:background="@color/red">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_white_36dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

         <!-- Your main layout here -->




   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
                      android:gravity="center"
                      android:layout_centerVertical="true">
            <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
                    android:layout_width="36dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:id="@+id/packaging"
                   android:src="@drawable/redmarkcheck"</LinearLayout></com.chauthai.swipereveallayout.SwipeRevealLayout>
```

Comment: In addition , I can set on each layout .setOnClickListner{
if(holder.swipelayout.isOpened){
viewbinderhelp.closeLayout("key string")
}
} but it only close when click on the layout that isOpened . My question is how do i test if one of the items in recyclerview is swiped opened ?

Comment: you can redirect to another library, works like a charm
 
https://android-pratap.blogspot.com/2015/07/swipe-recyclerview-using.html?m=1